# Get activity data from azure

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are using ADF V2
We are running 'master' pipelines that fire off other pipelines.
In the monitoring tab I can see per pipeline the number of activity runs ectetera.

In the costanalyses in Azure itself we only see a breakdown per datafactory and anything below that level is invisible to us. We need to know what the costs per 'master'pipeline are.

Is there a way to group this information per 'master'pipeline?
Can we download this information?

Or should we create multiple datafactories so that each datafactory has only one 'master'pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannt get cost of each 'master' pipeline when you have multiply 'master' pipelines in one data factory.
Cost analyses can only get cost at factory level. so if you want to get cost of each 'master' pipeline within cost analyses, you need to create multiply data factories as you said.